# Does X-inactivation lead to expression of sex-linked recessive disorders in half of carrier females' cells?

Tags: genetics, cell-biology

If one of the two X chromosomes in female mammals is randomly inactivated (i.e. becomes a Barr body) in each cell, shouldn't half of all cells in a female who is a carrier for an X-linked recessive disorder (say, Duchenne muscular dystrophy) express the disorder?

Comment: Similar question to: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/31635/in-human-females-one-x-chromosome-is-inactivated-forming-barr-body-then-how-exa

Answer (score 3):

Yes and No... You are correct that [X-Chromosome Inactivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-inactivation) will randomly inactivate the good X-chromosome (i.e. the one NOT carrying the mutation/disease) half of the time. However, this doesn't always seem to be associated with a disease phenotype. It likely depends on the gene and other factors, like the gene allele's function, to determine whether there is a disease phenotype that manifests with inactivation. [Check out this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3459813/) that looked at Duchenne muscular dystrophy in females that is available freely on PubMed.